# How to Read all inner recursive values from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping, wso2-esb

need to Extract Values from all levels of Recursive XML structure.The structurte in all levels is same

```
<regPackagingHierarchyList>
  <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
    <recordId>Level0</recordId>
    <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
      <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
        <recordId>level5</recordId>
        <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
          <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
            <recordId>level4</recordId>
            <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
              <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                <recordId>level3</recordId>
                <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
                  <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                    <recordId>level2</recordId>
                    <regParentPackagingHierarchy>
                      <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                        <recordId>level1</recordId>
                      </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                    </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
                  </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
                </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
              </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
            </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
          </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
        </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
      </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
    </regParentPackagingHierarchy>
  </RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
</regPackagingHierarchyList>
```

> Expected Result should be in the follwing format
>   Level1,Level2,Level3,level4,Level5

Comment: Could you have two `RegistrationPackagingHierarchy` elements that were siblings of each other, or will there only ever be one `RegistrationPackagingHierarchy` child per parent?

Comment: It will be always one child @TimC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way in 1.0 can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//regParentPackagingHierarchy//recordId">
        <xsl:sort select="position()" order="descending" />
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpv

**Edit:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat('Count(regPackagingHierarchyList) = ', count(//regPackagingHierarchyList))"/>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('Count(RegistrationPackagingHierarchy) = ', count(//RegistrationPackagingHierarchy))"/>
```

**Edit 2:**

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpv/8

Comment: Thank You so Much.. it's working as expected @Vebbie

Comment: How to take child nodes count for <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy> or <regPackagingHierarchyList> .
expected output is  **Count(regPackagingHierarchyList)=17**

Comment: @DhanaSekhar : Added that in the answer.

Comment: @Vibbie, got another Problem.<regPackagingHierarchyList> this is tag is repeating and while running your XSLT i am getting all Combined together.like **level1,level2,level3,level4,level5level1,level2,level3,level4,level5**. can you please Help me to fix this. Expected is in first Iteration i should get Iteration-1 ::level1,level2,level3,level4,level5 
Iteration2:level1,level2,level3,level4,level5
ll be waiting for your reply.
updated Here
[link](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifpv/7)

Comment: this is how XMl strcture will be 
**<regPackagingHierarchyList>
  <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>Parent Package LIST</RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
  <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>Parent Package LIST</RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
  <RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>Parent Package LIST</RegistrationPackagingHierarchy>
</regPackagingHierarchyList>**

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recordId">
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    <!-- Apply all the templates beneath first and output your id after they got applied. -->
    <xsl:if test="ancestor::regParentPackagingHierarchy">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```